# C++ boost regex replace with conditions

Tags: c++, regex, boost

## Context:

I am currently writing a date formatting library in C++. For example. the library takes in a formatting string such as: `dddd, mmmm d, dddd yyyy` and produces a result `Tuesday, December 26, Tuesday 2016` given year: 2016, month: 12, date: 26 (`dddd` stands for weekday, `d` stands for date in number, `mmmm` stands for month, `yyyy` stands for year).

I would like to achieve this by using `boost::regex_replace`.

## What I have tried:

### Javascript

---

In `javascript` I can easily achieve this by doing:

```
var pattern = 'dddd, mmmm d, yyyy';
pattern.replace(/(dddd)|(d)|(mmmm)|(yyyy)/gi, function (dddd, d, mmmm, yyyy){
    if (dddd) {
        return 'Tuesday';
    }

    if (d) {
        return '26'
    }

    if (mmmm) {
        return 'December';
    }

    if (yyyy) {
       return '2016';
    }
    return '';
}
```

### C++

---

```
boost::regex regex1("(dddd)");
boost::regex regex2("(d)");
boost::regex regex3("(mmmm)");
boost::regex regex4("(yyyy)");
boost::smatch match;

// dddd
if (boost::regex_search(pattern, match, regex1))
{
    pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, regex1, "Tuesday");
}

// d
if (boost::regex_search(pattern, match, regex2))
{
    pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, regex2, "26");
}

// mmmm
if (boost::regex_search(pattern, match, regex3))
{
        pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, regex3, "December");
}

// yyyy
if (boost::regex_search(pattern, match, regex4))
{
    pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, regex4, "2016");
}
```

However, that gives me a result of `"Tues26ay, December 26, Tues26ay 2016"`. The reason is that: as soon as I replace pattern `dddd` with `Tuesday`, the `d` inside `Tuesday` becomes a target pattern for `regex2` causing it to be replaced with `26`. 
I am not sure how to fix this problem or I think my C++ way for solving this problem is not correct. Is it possible to have something similar as Javascript in C++ boost::regex?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With Boost, you should be able to use conditional replacement patterns, like searching for `(dddd)|(d)|(mmmm)|(yyyy)` and replacing with `(?{1}Tuesday:?{2}26:?{3}December:2016)`

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/regex/doc/regex_replace.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you didn't literally 1-on-1 translate:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a055953ae995a2ce)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string pattern = "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy";
    pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, boost::regex("(dddd)|(d)|(mmmm)|(yyyy)"), [](auto& match)->std::string{
        if (match.str() == "dddd")
            return "Tuesday";

        if (match.str() == "d")
            return "26";

        if (match.str() == "mmmm")
            return "December";

        if (match.str() == "yyyy")
            return "2016";

        return "";
    });

    std::cout << "Result: " << pattern << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Result: Tuesday, December 26, 2016
```

Bonus:

- c++03 version [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9195375154a4e32)
- alternative match selection [C++11 on submatch index](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59125a8a05e391ce), [C++11 on named submatches](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bf9ab4b38599e1a)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the alternate versions too! Do you think it's possible to get the match's index so a switch could be used?

Comment: You can make it so if you want, but it's not there by default. After all, matches don't need to be exclusive (think `"(d(ddd))"`)

Comment: @PatLaugh A variant that passes the highest matched group-index to the callback [in c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b8bda8e43a8c11f) or [c++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6670b386cd83d5f7); here's another [solution that uses four arguments to the formatter callback](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f712f732dad85bb).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to replace the weekday by a control char that's sure not to be elsewhere, then at the end replace that with the proper weekday; I don't have boost, but it works with std::regex.

To add / modify:

```
boost::regex regex5("(\x01)");
//dddd
pattern = regex_replace(pattern, regex1, "\x01");
//then the fifth check
pattern = regex_replace(pattern, regex5, "Tuesday");
```

Comment: Yes that should work out as expected. Actually while I was waiting for the answer, I came up with similar ideas as yours except that yours is more safe by using control characters as placeholders. I will mark it as an accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, you can use a callback for the replacement formatter just like in javascript. See my answer