# boost::regex search and replace

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I'm writing a program that does string manipulations with [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref.html).
In all the cases I need the functionality of [`regex_search`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html), but only specific cases need [`regex_replace`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html).
Is there a way to combine the two so that *replacing* doesn't redo the work of *searching*?

I know that after calling

```
boost::regex re;
std::string str, fmt;
// . . .
boost::smatch match;
regex_search( str, match, re );
```

`match` contains information about matching, but

```
match.format( fmt );
```

doesn't do what

```
regex_replace( str, re, fmt );
```

does.

Comment: Can you please explain why you thought this was a bad question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a dynamic replacement: [C++ boost regex replace with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351316/c-boost-regex-replace-with-conditions/41352774#41352774)

> The sample there has a c++03, c++11 variants with named/unnamed submatches.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string pattern = "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy";
    pattern = boost::regex_replace(pattern, boost::regex("(dddd)|(d)|(mmmm)|(yyyy)"), [](auto& match)->std::string{
        if (match.str() == "dddd")
            return "Tuesday";

        if (match.str() == "d")
            return "26";

        if (match.str() == "mmmm")
            return "December";

        if (match.str() == "yyyy")
            return "2016";

        return "";
    });

    std::cout << "Result: " << pattern << "\n";
}
```